# Can not import ApifyWrapper from langchain.utilities to make web scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, langchain, apify, py-langchain

I can not import ApifyWrapper from langchain.utilities. I need to import it to make web scrapping from a web site for a school project.

I got this error:

**

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnLo9.png), line 3
> 1 from langchain.document_loaders.base import Document
> 2 from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
> ----> 3 from langchain.utilities import ApifyWrapper ImportError: cannot import name 'ApifyWrapper' from 'langchain.utilities'
> (C:\Users\USER2023\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\langchain\utilities_*init*_.py)

**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnLo9.png)

I have checked the Langchain documentation and found that apify.ipynb is located in the tools folder. Attached link: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/docs/extras/integrations/tools/apify.ipynb

Please suggestions to solve it.

Comment: at a guick glance(history), i could not find a trace of code for this wrapper in repo, pls refer this [open issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/8307) on github

Answer (score 1):

latest version(0.0.251) of langchain missing this Wrapper(need to dig more on it), so you can move back to the prior version.

```
pip install langchain==0.0.187
```

this version will work and import will be successful.

Comment: Now, do you know what version works with 'create_extraction_chain' from 'langchain.chains'? I can not import it. Please help me. Thank you for your response.